# how to fix error occurred during upgrade magento from 2.2 to 2.3?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, version

Process :  Upgrade Magento version from 2.2 to 2.3

As per my client requirement, I tried to upgrade Magento from 2.2 to 2.3 as mentioned in this URL: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

All steps were run properly but after run `composer update` command it will throw following Fatal error after some time as per mention into the screenshot.

[image]

And then after exit from **`composer update`** command.

Please suggest me how can I fix this error ?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be realted to **PHP compatibility** :

- For `Magento 2.3` : `PHP 7.1`
- For `Magento 2.2` : `PHP 7.1` or `PHP 7.0`

Check your PHP version, and upgrade or downgrade PHP if needed.

**You will never make Magento 2 works fine without the good version of PHP**

Comment: Thanks for reply bro

I used php 7.2 version and fresh installed magento 2.3.0 with php 7.2 works properly

Comment: now working ? @YagnikSolanki

Comment: No,
Trying to upgrade magneto version in php version 7.1 and once it will upgrade than run with php version 7.2

I hope it works.

Comment: I fixed above issue my way and magento was upgraded to 2.3.0